# Is there a free and open source 3D engine for Android?

Tags: 3d, android, open-source

Is there a free and unlimited open source 3D engine for Android? Something that is a direct, thin layer to the NDK?

I have only found two engines: Unity and Shiva 3D. But no free or open source ones.

Comment: Does it have to use NDK for everything (even code that isn't processor-bound)?

Answer (score 17):

Open Source C++ 3D Engine available for Android:

- [Ogre3D](http://www.ogre3d.org/): the best open source 3d engine but it is a large framework
- [Irrlicht](http://irrlicht.sourceforge.net/): good performance, light framework. I use it
- [libgdx](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/): Java API with NDK code

Comment: A quick Google search seems to reveal that Ogre3D support for Android seems to be not mature at the moment

Comment: Not mature but usable. If you want develop a real game, that's not the most difficult part. We (at IOPixel) are using Irrlicht as Engine3D but we have rewrite many parts... If you search simplicity and performance, Unity3D is a good choice.

Answer (score 4):

[Linderdaum Engine](http://www.linderdaum.com) 2D/3D open source engine in C++ for Windows and Android. All prototyping can be done on Windows. Also contains some Java code for JNI interoperation with Android SDK.

Answer (score 2):

**gamekit** is completely free even if you produce commercial venture with it. You can download it free at http://code.google.com/p/gamekit/.

Answer (score 1):

[OpenSceneGraph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenSceneGraph). Don't know about thin, but it runs on android.

Answer (score 1):

How about [Min3D](http://code.google.com/p/min3d/) ?