# Specifying 3D objects in a game

Tags: game-design, game-mechanics, opengl-es2

I have hands on experience in OpenGLES 2.0 , OpenGL and wish to apply the same in a 3D game development in Android. 
My idea is to develop a Combat game having fighter planes. I am trying to create a 3D mesh for plane.
Right now I am creating a model by myself so that I can keep the polycount low.Here z-axis is my reference i.e. the object is symmetric about z-axis. But when I apply rotation the depth test causes the components to look incorrect. Using z-axis as reference will make my ModelView matrix less expensive in terms of computation. 
How does one typically specify 3D objects in games ? Is .obj a good alternative ?

Also if you guys can provide some basic tutorials that will be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How does one typically specify 3D objects in games ? Is .obj a good alternative ?

.obj is one of the easiest 3D formats to parse if you're doing it yourself. You can also export it from just about any modeling software. (I recommend [Blender](http://blender.org), but whatever you do, definitely don't do it yourself in code).

However, it sounds like you might be just starting out with this stuff, in which case I recommend you find and use a game engine (maybe start [here](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/19219/is-there-a-free-and-open-source-3d-engine-for-android)) rather than trying to figure things out on your own. These problems have been solved a million times by thousands of other people, so why not use their work to your advantage?

Just an interesting side-note here:

> Using z-axis as reference will make my ModelView matrix less expensive in terms of computation.

I doubt that. It's generally more expensive for the graphics card to do an early-out test that checks for special cases (like z-axis aligned matrices) than it is to just do the multiplication. This is because GPUs are heavily parallel and pipelined, to the point where basically every time you do a branch, both paths are actually executed, and the "wrong" branch path just gets discarded.

At any rate, even if there were a performance benefit, it would not be noticeable at all, even with a very advanced profiler.

My advice is, don't worry about performance until it becomes an issue. Pre-mature optimization is a common trap developers fall into.

Anyway that's my two cents. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for the pointer ! And sorry guys for incorrect framing of question.